# Reciprocity and Time Reversal in Optics

Tags: optics, polarization, time-reversal-symmetry

I'm reading Chapter 1.9 of *Photonics* by Yariv and Yeh, and they're discussing general properties of Jones matrices for polarization of light.

The setup they suggest is the following. Let there be some set of birefringent optics that ultimately change the Jones vector of an input light beam. If we go one direction, say from $z=0$ to $z=L$, then we transform light with Jones vector $\mathbf{V}_{in}$ to light with Jones vector $\mathbf{V}_{out}$ via the Jones matrix $M$ of the system. Conversely, if we go the opposite way, we change an input light $\mathbf{U}_{in}$ to $\mathbf{U}_{out}$ via the Jones matrix $N$. The question they seek to answer is: how are $M$ and $N$ related?

Here's an extremely professional diagram:

[image]

They start by noting what happens in the case of time reversal symmetry. If we let $\mathbf{V}_{in}$ transform to $\mathbf{V}_{out}$, and then reverse time, we must get out the complex conjugate of what we put in, so $\mathbf{U}_{in} = (\mathbf{V}_{out})^*$ implies $\mathbf{U}_{out} = (\mathbf{V}_{in})^*$. That means that $NM^*=1$. (I get this: $\mathbf{U}_{out} = N\mathbf{U}_{in}$ so $(\mathbf{V}_{in})^* = N(M\mathbf{V}_{in})^* = NM^* (\mathbf{V}_{in})^*$. Fine.)

The next property they discuss really confuses me conceptually. It's the idea of reciprocity: if we interchange the source and the observer, we should observe the same field. The authors state that reciprocity implies $N=M^T$, where $T$ denotes the transpose. A couple of things are not clear to me:

- The conceptual statement above that I've seen online, that "interchange of source and observer does not change what we observe," makes me think that if I put in light with Jones vector $\mathbf{V}_{in}$, I should get $\mathbf{V}_{out}$ *regardless of which direction I put the light in*. Doesn't that mean $N=M$? What is wrong with that reasoning?
- I have seen proofs of the reciprocity theorem that suggest that reciprocity allows me to say $\mathbf{V}_{out} \cdot \mathbf{U}_{in} = \mathbf{V}_{in} \cdot \mathbf{U}_{out}$, and that does indeed imply $N=M^T$. But how could I see *conceptually* that those dot products are the ones related by reciprocity?
- How does reciprocity differ in this situation from time reversal? It clearly does since we get different conditions on $N$ and $M$ as a result.

The mathematical symptom of this confusion is no doubt that Jones matrices are unitary, so the transpose and conjugate are deeply related, but the authors *use the above* to show their unitarity, so I'd prefer we avoid assuming their unitarity to show anything; I'd like to understand the authors' logic if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A Jones matrix is not necessarily unitary, unless you restrict your attention to power-conserving Jones matrices.

Comment: Very true. In fact, I think if it's not power-conserving, time reversal doesn't hold, but reciprocity still does as long as the loss is independent of the polarization. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to help me understand my questions.